# Running continuous communications using QT and python

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer, serial-communication

I used to use TKinter for my GUIS and am now trying to move to QT Designer. I am also new to event based programming. What I am trying to do is listen to communication on my serial port continuously after a start button has been pressed.

I want to call a function update() which takes in the data and manipulates it and writes it to a file. It must then handle any other events queued up before calling update() again. Obviously if I use a while loop my CPU usage goes to 100% and my GUI becomes unresponsive.  In TKinter I got around this problem (messily) by using an after_idle call which called update() whenever the GUI was idle.

What is the best practice manner of doing this kind of thing using QT?

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread to monitor the serial port. Use appropriate mechanisms to communicate with the UI (main) thead.

That way you can write your comm module without worrying about the event base nature of the UI. Of course you still cannot use a busy while loop to listen to the serial port. But using the usual read() methods with a time out is ok.

A Queue is well suitable to send data to the UI, and you can write files directly from you comm thread.